# Nested classes are dependent types in class templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, dependent-name

Consider the following:

```
template<class> struct T
{
    struct T1
    {
        struct T2
        {

        };
    };
    /*typename*/ T1::T2 m;
};
```

Without `typename`, compilation fails as T2 is considered a dependent name, and thus not a type. After looking to a C++17 draft standard (N4659), I believe I've determined why:

§ 17.6.2.1 ¶ 5

> A name is a *member of the current instantiation* if it is
>   — An unqualified name that, when looked up, refers to at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation or a non-dependent base class thereof.
>   ...
>   A name is a *dependent member of the current instantiation* if it is a member of the current instantiation that, when looked up, refers to at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation.

T1 is a dependent member of the current instantiation. T2 is not a member of the current instantiation (it is a member of T1),

§ 17.6.2.1 ¶ 9.3

> A type is dependent if it is
>   ...
>   — a nested class or enumeration that is a dependent member of the current instantiation,
>   ...

T1 is a nested class and thus a dependent type.

§ 17.6 ¶ 3

> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation (17.6.2.1) and its *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword **typename**, forming a *typename-specifier*. ...

Thus, `typename` is needed.

Is my understanding correct? If so, what's the rationale behind this? How could the lookup of `T1::T2` ever find anything other than the T2 nested within T1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

In your case it doesn't matter because you cannot possibly specialize `T1` without instantiating `m` (as it is a class member). But you could do this, put `m` in a function:

```
template<class> struct T
{
    struct T1
    {
        struct T2
        {

        };
    };

    void foo() {
        typename T1::T2 m;
    }
};

template<>
struct T<void>::T1 {
    int T2;
};
```

If `T1` were not dependent, your code could possibly change meaning because `T2` would refer to a value and not a type.